# Camera2 API not respecting CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE

Tags: android, android-camera2

I'm trying to set the maximum Exposure time of the camera to be the shortest available on the phone. All the phones I'm using provide a Range of (30,30) which means 1/30th of second.

However I find that in lot of cases the phone still captures photos at 1/10th of a second.

From the docs regarding **CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE**:

> Range over which the auto-exposure routine can adjust the capture frame rate to maintain good exposure.
> Only constrains auto-exposure (AE) algorithm, not manual control of android.sensor.exposureTime and android.sensor.frameDuration.

My code:

```
val ranges = cameraCharacteristics?.get(CameraCharacteristics.CONTROL_AE_AVAILABLE_TARGET_FPS_RANGES)
if(!ranges.isNullOrEmpty()){
 extender.setCaptureRequestOption(CaptureRequest.CONTROL_AE_TARGET_FPS_RANGE,ranges.sortedWith(compareBy({ it.lower }, { it.upper })).last())
}
```

Result:

```
ExifTool Version Number         : 10.80
File Name                       : xxx.webp
Directory                       : .
File Size                       : 136 kB
File Modification Date/Time     : 2020:12:10 10:16:33+01:00
File Access Date/Time           : 2021:01:04 16:28:19+01:00
File Inode Change Date/Time     : 2020:12:23 09:50:03+01:00
File Permissions                : rw-rw-r--
File Type                       : WEBP
File Type Extension             : webp
MIME Type                       : image/webp
VP8 Version                     : 0 (bicubic reconstruction, normal loop)
Image Width                     : 3264
Horizontal Scale                : 0
Image Height                    : 1836
Vertical Scale                  : 0
Exif Byte Order                 : Big-endian (Motorola, MM)
Make                            : samsung
Camera Model Name               : SM-A705FN
Orientation                     : Horizontal (normal)
X Resolution                    : 72
Y Resolution                    : 72
Resolution Unit                 : inches
Software                        : A705FNXXU3ASI2
Modify Date                     : 2020:12:09 15:49:41
Y Cb Cr Positioning             : Centered
Exposure Time                   : 1/10
F Number                        : 1.7
Exposure Program                : Program AE
ISO                             : 1169
Exif Version                    : 0220
Date/Time Original              : 2020:12:09 15:49:41
Create Date                     : 2020:12:09 15:49:41
Components Configuration        : Y, Cb, Cr, -
Shutter Speed Value             : 1/10
Aperture Value                  : 1.7
Brightness Value                : -5.79
Exposure Compensation           : 0
Max Aperture Value              : 1.7
Metering Mode                   : Center-weighted average
Light Source                    : Unknown
Flash                           : No Flash
Focal Length                    : 3.9 mm
Sub Sec Time                    : 039986
Sub Sec Time Original           : 039986
Sub Sec Time Digitized          : 039986
Flashpix Version                : 0100
Color Space                     : sRGB
Exif Image Width                : 3264
Exif Image Height               : 1836
Interoperability Index          : R98 - DCF basic file (sRGB)
Sensing Method                  : Not defined
Scene Type                      : Directly photographed
Exposure Mode                   : Auto
White Balance                   : Auto
Focal Length In 35mm Format     : 26 mm
Scene Capture Type              : Standard
Image Unique ID                 : B32QLLA01MM B32QLLA01MM
Aperture                        : 1.7
Image Size                      : 3264x1836
Megapixels                      : 6.0
Scale Factor To 35 mm Equivalent: 6.6
Shutter Speed                   : 1/10
Create Date                     : 2020:12:09 15:49:41.039986
Date/Time Original              : 2020:12:09 15:49:41.039986
Modify Date                     : 2020:12:09 15:49:41.039986
Circle Of Confusion             : 0.005 mm
Field Of View                   : 69.4 deg
Focal Length                    : 3.9 mm (35 mm equivalent: 26.0 mm)
Hyperfocal Distance             : 2.00 m
Light Value                     : 1.3
```

The Exposure Mode is set to Auto, but the capture does not respect the max Exposure time I've set.